# Paho-Mqtt Periodic Publications approaches

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

What is the best way to publish safely data periodically ?

First approach:

```
while(true){
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    //pub
}
```

second:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                //pub
                }
             }
```

third:

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { //pub }
        }, 0, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Without a lot of context of exactly what you are doing where, you are asking for an opinion and Stack Overflow really isn't the place for this sort of question.

Comment: the context i think is directly available periodic publications in java / paho lib which approach is preferable and best suited for ciriticall apps

Comment: All 3 methods do the same thing, it totally depends on the architecture of the rest of your application as to which fits best